# BeforePost gravando informação errada

Tags: delphi, firebird

Em minha aplicação Delphi, ao quebrar um acordo com meu Cliente devo atualizar os dados das operações!

Então eu começo excluindo alguns dados do Cliente, o problema acontece justamente nessa parte:

```
procedure TDMClientes.QOperacoesBeforePost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  QuebrarAcordo(DMClientes.QOperacoesBanco.AsInteger,
                DMClientes.QOperacoesCLIENTE.AsInteger,
                DMClientes.QOperacoesNROPERACAO.AsString,
                DMClientes.QOperacoesREMESSA.AsInteger,
                V_CodEvento_Quebra,true);
end;
```

No código acima eu chamo uma função `QuebrarAcordo` que esta em outra `unit`, lá funciona corretamente:

```
ExecSql('UPDATE OPERACOES SET VALOR_DIVIDA = VALOR_ORIGINAL WHERE CLIENTE = XXXXXX');
```

O Sql é executado corretamente e volta para finalizar o `BeforePost`, mas esta acontecendo um Roolback na Base de Dados!

O que pode estar causando esse roolback sem aviso algum de erro?

Comment: esse `DataSet` é componente de terceiros ou é nativo, caso for terceiro verifique se possui a propriedade `AutoCommit`, e informe como ela esta!

Comment: Possui, mas esta falso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que não esta ocorrendo um *RoolBack*, vamos por partes...

Você iniciou um transação com o banco que chamou o `BeforePost` do componente, então o `DataSet` esta em modo de Edição, ai você chamou uma função que executa um Update diretamente na Base de Dados.

Ate ai realmente esta tudo bem, mas ao voltar e completar o BeforePost adivinha? O `BeforePost` vai fazer um post (ou seja um commit) na sua Base de Dados gravando tudo que o componente já iria gravar!

Então, dentro do `BeforePost`, antes de chamar a função, você deve Cancelar o estado de Edição do DataSet. Experimente deixar seu procedimento dessa forma:

```
procedure TDMClientes.QOperacoesBeforePost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  DMClientes.QOperacoesBanco.Cancel; //Cancela a edição que chamou o BeforePost
  QuebrarAcordo(DMClientes.QOperacoesBanco.AsInteger,
                DMClientes.QOperacoesCLIENTE.AsInteger,
                DMClientes.QOperacoesNROPERACAO.AsString,
                DMClientes.QOperacoesREMESSA.AsInteger,
                V_CodEvento_Quebra,true);
    DMClientes.QOperacoes.Refresh; //Atualiza o Componente, pois, ouve alterações
    DMClientes.QOperacoes.Edit; //Coloca novamente em Edição para finalizar outras alterações
end;
```

Mas... o ideal seria ao invés de chamar uma função externa ao `BeforePost` você executar o Update ali mesmo:

```
procedure TDMClientes.QOperacoesBeforePost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  ExecSql('UPDATE OPERACOES SET VALOR_DIVIDA = VALOR_ORIGINAL WHERE CLIENTE = XXXXXX');
end;
```

Claro, caso não haja a necessidade de chamar a função!

**Edit:**

Outra maneira mais decente de fazer (teoricamente mais correta) seria você passar uma variável Booleana `true` (validando que deve executar a função externa), e no `AfterPost` verificar a variável e executar a chamada da Função, deixando o `BeforePost` Limpo de códigos adicionais `Cancel`, `Refresh` e `Edit`.

Explicando, quando o procedimento chega no `AfterPost`, significa que o componente já saiu do modo de edição e já esta com as informações atualizadas, não precisando mais de comando adicionais! Então, bastaria validar se a variável esta em `True` e executar a chamada da função externa!

Comment: Eu não posso executar direto, por que existem outras validações dentro do `BeforePost`, mas sua solução funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues, agora em casa atoa acabei dando uma revisada, analisa por favor e confirma se encaixa melhor essa abordagem!